# App crashing after exiting MapBoxMap Activity

Tags: java, error-handling, mapbox, mapbox-android, rnmapbox-maps

Whenever I exit the activity that holds the Mapbox map, the application crashes and this error message appears in my log:

W/mbgl-locationSymbol: Style is not fully loaded, not able to get source!

This is what my @onDestroy looks like:

```
  @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mapboxMap != null) {
           mapView.onDestroy();
        }
        

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the following code to onDestroy resolved this issue:

```html
  @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mapboxMap != null) {
            mapboxMap.removeOnMapClickListener(this);
            mapView.removeOnDidFinishLoadingStyleListener(this::onDestroy);
            mapView.onStop();
        }
        mapView.onDestroy();

    }
```

Comment: You should accept this answer by clicking the green checkmark next to the answer. That will remove the question from the list of open questions and maybe help someone else who has this problem.